# Iptables - Port forwarding has no effect

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I have a dedicated server with a single public IP (Say 1.2.3.4) running CentOS. 
Via virt-manager, I added a virtual machine, running CentOS as well.

They are connected through a virtual network:

- Host is on 192.168.100.1
- Guest is on 192.168.100.2

My goal is to set up a TeamSpeak server on the Guest, accessible by the Host's public IP.

Browsing forums, I ended up with those rules :

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 9987 -j DNAT --to 192.168.100.2:9987
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.100.2 -p udp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m udp --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 30033 -j DNAT --to 192.168.100.2:30033
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.100.2 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 30033 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 30033 -j DNAT --to 192.168.100.2:30033
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.100.2 -p udp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m udp --dport 30033 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -i eth0 --dport 10011 -j DNAT --to 192.168.100.2:10011
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.100.2 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 10011 -j ACCEPT
```

Unfortunately, I get no response when trying to connect using TeamSpeak.

Would you please enlighten me ?

------------------------------------ EDIT ------------------------------------

Running "tcpdump -i eth0 -n udp port 9987" on both machines, I can see forwarded packets.

vi /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

netstat -an|grep -w 9987

```
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9987                0.0.0.0:*
```

LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 10/sec burst 5 LOG level warning

```
Jun 21 04:17:07 sd-xxxxx kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:0c:c4:7a:08:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=62.xx.xx.52 DST=62.xx.xx.255 LEN=49 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=45280 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=47579 DPT=32414 LEN=29 
Jun 21 04:17:09 sd-xxxxx kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:0c:c4:7a:09:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=62.xx.xx.188 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=201 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=65 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=55996 DPT=1900 LEN=181
```

I found rule for port 9987 isn't described the same way in iptables -L 's FORWARD block

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 10/sec burst 5 LOG level warning 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.100.2       state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp dpt:10011 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.100.2       state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED udp dpt:30033 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             192.168.100.2       state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED tcp dpt:30033 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             192.168.100.2       state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED udp dpt:dsm-scm-target 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Got no log adding the rules below, neither on Host nor on Guest

```
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: " --log-level 4
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

Comment: Did you enable routing/IP forwarding on the host ?

Comment: Is there a firewall running on the host?

Comment: @Iain 
I set net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1 in /etc/sysctl.conf and restarted Host. 
Is it what you mean ?

Comment: @MadHatter 
Host is running iptables with aforementioned rules. 
Iptables service is stopped on Guest

Comment: Hmm.  OK.  Just to cover the obvious, could we get the output of `netstat -an|grep -w 9987` on the guest?

Comment: @MadHatter On both Host and Guest, the output is as follows : 
    udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9987                0.0.0.0:*

Comment: OK, that's not it, either.  Some casual reading suggests that for TS to work properly, you also need to allow TCP/10011, TCP/30033 and UDP/30033.  Are you sure you're opening up enough ports for TS to work?  What are the host's firewall logs saying when you try to make an application-level connection.

Comment: @MadHatter
Added similar rules for these ports : same result. 
Enabling iptables logging outputs entries similar to those : 

Jun 21 04:17:07 sd-xxxxx kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:0c:c4:7a:08:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=62.xx.xx.52 DST=62.xx.xx.255 LEN=49 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=45280 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=47579 DPT=32414 LEN=29 
Jun 21 04:17:09 sd-xxxxx kernel: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:0c:c4:7a:09:xx:xx:xx:xx SRC=62.xx.xx.188 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=201 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=65 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=55996 DPT=1900 LEN=181

Comment: @Vincent: Please include the log inside your question, it's really hard to read in the comments.

Comment: Are those firewall entries from the client from which you are trying to make a TS connection?  Those will be the interesting firewall logs, not just every random refused packet.

Comment: @MadHatter Those are from the Host. Firewall is disabled on Guest (service iptables stop). Client is, IMO, not in cause because it can connect to Host's TS Server when Prerouting/Forward rules aren't applied. Btw, thank you for sparing time to help me.

Comment: Sorry, I have been unclear.  I understand the firewall entries are from the host, I want to know if they relate to the TS client's attempt to make a TS connection to the guest, or if they are just random firewall logs.  I'm mostly interested in the ones that show the client's IP address, you see.